# Joi validation of array based on index

Tags: joi

In [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v14.3.0/API.md) is there any way to validate elements of an array based on its index?

For example i have an array of strings and only last of them can be `'end'`.

Comment: It's possible to validate the _first_ element of an array ([here](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#arrayorderedtype)) but I've not found a way to validate the last. In this instance you'll likely need to define your own [custom extension](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#extendextension).

Comment: @Ankh thanks! Yeah, i've seen this too. I just thought there should be something like this as the task looks common to me. I'd like to avoid extensions so asking here. Will go with extensions if there's no other way.